# Selecting xpath or css using parameters within data-bind

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to select element (Radio button) within a window using the label for the radio button

O id

O test

Trying to select radio button for 'id' by passing 'id'as a parameter in xpath or css selector

Tried `//span[@class="radio-text"][contains(text(),"${option}")]`, but it errors out saying span is not clickable. Trying to find something starting with `//label` (selects all the radio buttons without the text - which is what I am trying to select but only the one for the specified text)

```
....mi-radio data-bind="miRadioProperty:{
~

                checked: $root.refDocEntityKey,
                name:'refdocradiogroup',
                disable: false,
                value: $data.entyKey,
                text: $data.id
                }" style="">

<div class="radio-container" tabindex="0" style="">
    <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: $root.checked,disable: $root.disable,value:$root.value, attr:{id:$data.id , name:$root.name, required:$root.required} " value="64263096193" id="uobrsqyi-rfwd-vsjl-jxpu-akqqsuzzbfta" name="refdocradiogroup" style="">
    <label data-bind="attr:{for:$data.id}" for="uobrsqyi-rfwd-vsjl-jxpu-akqqsuzzbfta" style="background: rgb(204, 136, 136); border: 2px solid red;"></label>
    <span class="radio-text" data-bind="text: $root.text, click: $data.textClick" style="">id</span>
</div>
```

~

Expected:

Select and click the radio button with the value that is passed via a selector

Comment: It looks like you didn't get the full HTML at the start of the HTML that you posted. You'll have to fix that, I fixed the rest. You also didn't tag your desired language and you didn't provide any sample code of your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML provided, the locator with the desired value included would be

```
//span[@class='radio-text'][.='id']
```

How you deal with inserting the parameter into the string will depend on the language you are using, e.g. for Java it would be

```
"//span[@class='radio-text'][.='" + option + "']"
```

where `option` is the desired text. If you want a language specific answer, you'll have to tag your question with a language tag but this should be enough to get you pointed in the right direction with a little googling of inserting a variable into a string in your given language.